# Mysql - How can I delete data from tables and connection table in one query

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have 3 table in a mysql database: users, salesmanagers and the connection table is user_salesmanager which contains only 3 columns: id, userID and salesmanagerID.
How can I delete one salesmanager which has a foreign key?
I tried several ways, but isn't working:

```
DELETE u, s, us
    FROM `users` AS u
    LEFT JOIN `salesmanagers` AS s ON s.id=us.salesmanagerID
    LEFT JOIN `user_salesmanagers` AS us ON u.id=us.userID
WHERE u.id = 12
```

```
DELETE u, s, us
    FROM `user_salesmanagers` AS us
    LEFT JOIN `salesmanagers` AS s ON s.id=us.salesmanagerID
    LEFT JOIN `users` AS u ON us.userID=u.id
WHERE u.id = 12
```

```
BEGIN;
    SELECT u.id, us.id AS suid, s.id AS sid
        FROM `users` AS u
        LEFT JOIN `user_salesmanagers` AS us ON u.id=us.userID
        LEFT JOIN `salesmanagers` AS s ON us.`salesmanagerID`=s.id
        WHERE u.id = 12;
    SET @del_user_id = u.id
    SET @del_salesmanager_id = s.id
    SET @del_user_salesmanager_id = us.id;  

    DELETE FROM `user_salesmanagers` WHERE `id`=@del_user_salesmanager_id;
    DELETE FROM `users` WHERE `id`=@del_user_id;
    DELETE FROM `salesmanagers` WHERE `id`=@del_salesmanager_id;

COMMIT;
```

```
BEGIN;
    SELECT * FROM `user_salesmanagers`
    WHERE userID = 12;
    SET @del_user_id = `user_salesmanagers`.`userID`;
    SET @del_salesmanager_id = `user_salesmanagers`.`salesmanagerID`;
    DELETE FROM `user_salesmanagers` WHERE `userID`=@del_user_id;
    DELETE FROM `users` WHERE `id`=@del_user_id;
    DELETE FROM `salesmanagers` WHERE `id`=@del_salesmanager_id;
COMMIT;
```

Thanks!

Comment: Have you consider using CASCADE ? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html#foreign-key-referential-actions

Comment: Noway. You may delete all rows from junction table relative to deleted salesmanager, but you cannot delete all users mentioned in deleted juncion rows because some of them may be relative to another salesmanager(s).

Comment: @SeeoX Thanks, the CASCADE isn't a good solution, have you any other idea?

Comment: You may create service EVENT procedure executed periodically (for example, daily) which garbages the list of "lost" rows and deletes them (or moves to some archive).

Answer (score 0):

When I understand this right the user and salesmanagers are connected by user_salesmanagers. Instead of a _ I would use a 2 so it is more clear that this is a connection table, but only an advice from me.

Where have you declared the foreign keys and with which action?

I believe

```
DELETE `u`, `s`, `us`
    FROM `users` AS `u`
    LEFT JOIN `user_salesmanagers` AS `us` ON `u`.`id` = `us`.`userID`
    LEFT JOIN `salesmanagers` AS `s` ON `s`.`id` = `us`.`salesmanagerID` 
WHERE `u`.`id` = 12
```

should work.